# Generate summary / table statistics based on data type in R

Tags: r

I want to write an automated code in R for generating summary and table.

Statistics for variables based on their data types. for. e.g

```
If data type = Numeric, display summary();

If data type = factor, display table();
```

Please help me.

Thanks
Balaji

Comment: You need `if (is.numeric(x)) { ... } else if (is.factor(x)) { ... } else { ... }`. Is there something else to this?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
data <- data.frame(a=rnorm(4), b=c("a", "a", "b", "b"), c=c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE))

Display <- function(x) {
    switch(
    EXPR = class(x),
    factor = {
       print(table(x))
    },
    numeric = {
       print(summary(x))
    },
    print("not supported type")
    )
 }

 Display(data$a)
 Display(data$b)
 Display(data$c)
```